# Is possible drag drop files into standard html textarea?

Tags: html, jquery, drag-and-drop, textarea

I would like to know if it possible add drag and drop files to a standard HTML tag `<textarea>` and the same time it have the write too? Similiar stackoverflow textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTML5, you can drag and drop text content as follows:

CSS:

```
#tadrop{
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.value = document.getElementById(data).innerHTML;
  //jQuery: ev.target.value = $('#'+data).text();
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Drag SOME TEXT into the rectangle:</p>

<textarea id="tadrop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></textarea>

<p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">SOME TEXT</p>
```

Here's fiddle: [text drag and drop to `textarea`](https://jsfiddle.net/mbratch/qyvbk96w/4/).